# Large background image in html page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that have some large images inside some divs that cover the background of the page. I however get some strange issue with the page on viewing the page on Android pad where the page is viewed in portrait (looks ok on landscape viewing). The page get a blue (same color as background) on the right hand part of the screen next to the scrollbar (see images below). It might look to me like the page initially gets scaled wrong and then when you pinch zoom out you can see the blue are. Like the images did not get drawn all the way or something.

In the head of the page I have put the following tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The I have defined some divs to place the images:

```
<div class="homebg_top">...</div>
```

I have 4 of those divs with different background inside of them.

Then in the following in the css (for the above specific div):

```
.homebg_top {
    background: url(../images/bg_home_top.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 807px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The picture below is the page when in landscape mode:

[image]

The picture below is when it is in portrait mode 
(note the blue background issue next to scrollbar):

[image]

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions so far, but unfortunatly none of them worked.The height of the image is larger then the hight of the "visual space" so the fixed property will not work because it will scroll the content but the background gets hidden by content further down on the page when scrolling to the bottom of the page.

The cover property did not work either. The blue part of the window still gets shown when changing from landscape to portrait in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.homebg_top { 
   background: url(../images/bg_home_top.jpg) no-repeat center top /cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example : 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

```
.homebg_top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 807px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    background: url(../images/bg_home_top.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try thisone:

```
.homebg_top{ 
      background: url(http://media02.hongkiat.com/oversized-background-image-design/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://media02.hongkiat.com/oversized-background-image-design/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.http://media02.hongkiat.com/oversized-background-image-design/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    }
```

you can see this page http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/oversized-background-image-design/